# How long should it take to refresh a Developer Sandbox?

Tags: sandbox, sandbox-refresh

I refreshed a Developer Sandbox, and almost 24 hours it is still "pending". Is this normal? Are there any actions I can take to speed up the process? When I created the Sandbox it took barely more than 10 minutes to create.

Thanks,
Adrian

Comment: I initiated the creating of a developer sandbox two days ago. Still Pending / In queue. I just logged a case with Salesforce, because this is ridiculous. I wanted a new sandbox to investigate and solve an issue, and 48 hours later I'm still stuck... I initiated the creation of another one, see if that one gets served faster (probably not, but you have to try something).

Comment: One hour after logging the case, my sandbox is ready for use. Coincedence?

Comment: After having closed the case myself, Salesforce support contacted me. They told me that currently there is a backlog and, no, they hadn't advanced my sandbox creation in the queue, it was its proper turn. So: yes, a coincidence.

Comment: A partial sandbox refresh is now taking north of 6 days
Developer sandbox initiated at the same time hasn't even started! We escalated multiple times and heaven knows how long it would have taken otherwise Salesforce needs to figure this out, it should never take multiple days to get new sandboxes spun up or refreshes done.....ridiculous

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A status of *Pending* means, the sandbox refresh still hasn't started because other people's sandbox refresh requests are ahead of your request in the queue. Therefore, Salesforce doesn't provide SLA time. There's nothing much you can do but wait (indefinitely). Yes it is true that sometimes it can range from seconds to days to get to the front of this queue.

After your request reaches the front of the queue, the status would change from *Pending* to *Processing* and then to *Ready for activation*. Just for the sake of completeness, after you click the *Activate* link, the status would change to *Activating* and then to *Created*.

Since it is a developer sandbox, I'd not worry after crossing the *Pending* status. It should be fairly quick during the *Processing* status. There is no data to be copied, except for Custom Settings data. There are no slow queues and no fast queues for developer sandboxes - those are only for full sandboxes.

Related question: [What is the maximum time taken for the refresh of a full-copy sandbox?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14412/what-is-the-maximum-time-taken-for-the-refresh-of-a-full-copy-sandbox)

Comment: `A sandbox is not a point-in-time snapshot of the exact state of your data. Furthermore, we recommend that you limit changes to your production org while a sandbox is being created or refreshed. Setup and data changes to your production org during the sandbox creation and refresh operations can result in inconsistencies in your sandbox. You might detect and correct some inconsistencies in your sandbox after it is created or refreshed.`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the number of customizations, data size, numbers of objects and configuration choices if you are having a full copy of your production. It also depends on server load. 
Bare in mind that sandboxes refreshes are queued. I read somewhere that there are two types. Slow queue and fast queue. If you are copying a large data source then you are listed on the slow queue. If it's small size data then you are on the fast queue. So to answer your question. Refresh time varies on the size of data etc of copying and the server load

Comment: Weird, I'm not copying any data, just the standard objects and our three custom object.

Comment: It depends on server load though as well. I had a sandbox refresh with just standard objects and took near to two days. Please be kind and mark the answer as the best answer if it helped you. Thank you