# Sandbox provisioning taking over 48 hours

Tags: sandbox, sandbox-refresh

one of our customers requested a dev sandbox refresh on Monday (over 48 hours ago) and it is still listed as "Pending / In Queue" on CS50 (original org is on AP2). Is this normal on CS50?

Comment: I think this question has already been asked: [How long should it take to refresh a Developer Sandbox?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/68751/how-long-should-it-take-to-refresh-a-developer-sandbox)

Comment: It's ok guys, trust.salesforce.com says salesforce is running perfectly!

Comment: @AdrianLarson I'd almost finished answering, and then saw your link, which had a link to an answer I wrote almost verbatim...

Comment: Yeah I saw you had answered that one. Good times. Over a week. Yeesh! I've definitely seen 5+ days.

Comment: We created a sandbox on 25th August, it's been a week and it's still in queue!

Answer (score 0):

We requested a sandbox refresh about 30 hours ago on from AP1 and it's still "Pending / In Queue".

I requested a new sandbox for another org this morning (AP2) and it's still "Pending / In Queue".

I've found most sandboxes have been taken 8-12 hours for me lately.