# What is happening when a new sandbox is being activated?

Tags: sandbox

Just out of curiosity. I understand that there is a "copying" phase when creating sandboxes. But what does "activating" mean? The most recent activation took 12 hours. As a techie, I am wondering what on earth it is doing that takes so much time?

Edited: made more specific about the activation of new sandboxes. Added the final duration of activation.

Answer (score 2):

So far the information about [activation of sandbox](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_sandbox_create.htm) i have found is this:

> **Activating a replacement sandbox that was created using the Refresh
> link deletes the sandbox it is refreshing. The current configuration
> and data are erased, including application or data changes that you’ve
> made.**
>
> Click the Activate link only if you don’t need the current
> contents of the sandbox. Your production org and its data aren’t
> affected.
>
> New sandboxes that aren’t activated within 30 days are
> deleted. We send at least two email notifications before we schedule
> the sandbox for deletion.
>
> Users who have created or most recently
> refreshed any sandbox for your org receive the notifications.

For more information on sandbox you can visit this link  [Sandbox Setup Tips and Considerations](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14412/what-is-the-maximum-time-taken-for-the-refresh-of-a-full-copy-sandbox)

There is an idea here to [Activate a Sandbox immediately after Refresh](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Br6IAAS).

Comment: [Auto activation](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_deployment_sandbox_autoactivate.htm) is already a feature since Spring 16'.

Comment: @RobinDeBondt nice.I guess this idea didn't get enough points to mark it out as delivered.That's why it is still in Under Point Threshold.Or there is anything more it covers?

Comment: @Mr.Frodo Thanks for the answer. I have edited my question to make it more specific about the activation of new sandboxes.